# Switching value of boolean field with update method in Django

Tags: django, models

I have a model instance which has a boolean field on it. What I want to achieve is to switch the value from True to False or vice versa.

Surely, I can just write:

```
inst = Model.objects.get(id=1)
inst.boolean_field = not inst.boolean_field
inst.save()
```

But there are 2 queries: one for fetching and another one for updating.

I'd like just to switch the values, but the following does not seem to work:

```
Model.objects.filter(id=1).update(boolean_field=not F("boolean_field"))
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong or it's just not possible.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Case` instead:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

queryset.update(active=Case(
    When(active=True, then=Value(False)),
    When(active=False, then=Value(True)),
))
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, negation of `F() object` is not yet supported in django.

When you do `not F('boolean_field')` it gets evaluated to `True`, so the update operation always saves `True`. e.g.

```
>>> F('boolean_field')
<django.db.models.expressions.F object at 0x36b7d50>
>>> not F('boolean_field')
True
```

Refer this bug on django [17186 - Inverted F expression (negation)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17186)